# How to set initialize and set value to data class parameter LiveData in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata

Here is my data class

**SaleData(dataclass)**

```
data class SaleData(
    var saleType: Int = 1,
    var saleDetail: Int,
    var salePrice: Int,
    var saleRate: Int,
    var printAmount: Int
)
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val _saleData: MutableLiveData<SaleData> = MutableLiveData()
val saleData: LiveData<SaleData>
    get() = _saleData
init {
    
    _saleData.value?.saleType = 1
    
    changeSaleType()
}

fun changeSaleType() {
    _saleData.value?.saleType = 2
}
```

But Log the saleType like Log.d("DataLog","" + saleData.value?.saleType), it returns null.
I changed the saleType to Int,

```
private val _saleType: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
val saleType: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _saleType
```

It returns the data successfully.
So I have a question.
How save and inquire the liveata value of the object class?

Comment: As far as I know, setting data to  livedata does not apply immediately. It's because it's used to be observed when changed. However, You can initate your livedata like this ; 
private val _saleData: MutableLiveData<SaleData> = MutableLiveData(SaleData(...)), giving it a default value.

Comment: @March3April4 Thanks, but not immediately I'm not sure that's the right way to store values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_saleData.value?.saleType = 1
```

here you have to initialize livedata value with not null object
soz if you have `SaleData` class:

```
_saleData.value = SaleData()
```

after it, value wont be null

Comment: Thanks, In case of object, I realized that I have to proceed after initializing it once.